# SQL Left Join with Count

Tags: sql, join

I'm working on a video game inventory website. Here is a simplified version of my database tables along with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `platforms` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `platforms` VALUES(1, 'Nintendo');
INSERT INTO `platforms` VALUES(2, 'Super Nintendo');
INSERT INTO `platforms` VALUES(3, 'Nintendo 64');

--

CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `platform_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(1, 1, 'Super Mario Bros.');
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(2, 1, 'Super Mario Bros. 2');
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(3, 2, 'Super Mario World');
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(4, 2, 'Super Mario Kart');
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(5, 3, 'Super Mario 64');
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES(6, 3, 'Mario Kart 64');

--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(1, 'john_doe', '$2a$10$cQhc4VAXVMEyC1tA.VRoWunpNVi7392adacT/weVBzu6XGI6.Jx/K');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(2, 'jane_doe', '$2a$10$Ot2BmlT14hKDxHGIV8jBx.lW76HCWdwuOhNGIYrJO5O7BEtDUWLWu');

--

CREATE TABLE `games_users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `games_users` VALUES(1, 1, 1, '2013-04-12 12:18:09');
INSERT INTO `games_users` VALUES(2, 3, 1, '2013-04-12 12:18:42');
INSERT INTO `games_users` VALUES(3, 4, 1, '2013-04-12 12:19:13');
INSERT INTO `games_users` VALUES(4, 2, 2, '2013-04-12 12:19:32');
```

As you can see, john_doe has 1 Nintendo game (Super Mario Bros.), 2 Super Nintendo games (Super Mario World and Super Mario Kart), and 0 Nintendo 64 games. jane_doe has 1 Nintendo game (Super Mario Bros. 2), 0 Super Nintendo games, and 0 Nintendo 64 games.

I want to write a query specific to a user that will list all of the consoles and also list the number of games the user has for each console.

This is what the results would be for john_doe:

```
platform.id: 1
platform.name: Nintendo
game_count: 1

platform.id: 2
platform.name: Super Nintendo
game_count: 2

platform.id: 3
platform.name: Nintendo 64
game_count: 0
```

This is what the results would be for jane_doe:

```
platform.id: 1
platform.name: Nintendo
game_count: 1

platform.id: 2
platform.name: Super Nintendo
game_count: 0

platform.id: 3
platform.name: Nintendo 64
game_count: 0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: have you even tried something...?

Comment: @HmxaMughal I don't know where to start. Sorry, I'm not very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, IFNULL(t.cnt, 0)
FROM platforms p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT g.platform_id as 'id', COUNT(g.id) as cnt
  FROM users u
  JOIN games_users gu ON gu.user_id = u.id
  JOIN games g ON g.id = gu.game_id
  WHERE u.username = "jane_doe"
  GROUP BY g.platform_id
  ) t ON t.id = p.id
```

***[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6104d/36)***

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(g.id) FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN games_users gu ON u.id = gu.user_id 
LEFT JOIN games g ON g.id = gu.game_id 
LEFT JOIN platforms p ON g.platform_id = p.id 
WHERE u.id = 1 
GROUP BY p.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6104d/6

If you want to see the 0's you have to do some cheating I guess, here is how I achieved it. I got the sum of user_id (since they are all the same) and divide by user_id.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, IFNULL(SUM(user_id),0)/1 FROM platforms p 
LEFT JOIN games g ON g.platform_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN games_users gu ON g.id = gu.game_id AND gu.user_id = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name


SELECT p.id, p.name, IFNULL(SUM(user_id),0)/2 FROM platforms p 
LEFT JOIN games g ON g.platform_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN games_users gu ON g.id = gu.game_id AND gu.user_id = 2
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Comment: This is close... but it doesn't show Nintendo 64 with 0 games. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @summea Yes, but john_doe doesn't own any of them.